# React-select cypress

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress, react-select

i want to test a combobox (react-select) with cypress, i got this error, can anyone help me in that? or is there another way to choose an option from the react-select combobox and test it?
**Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<input#Land>' to have value 'Angola', but the value was ''**

```
    <div class=" css-1kszcc2-container">
     <span id="react-select-2-live-region" class="css-1f43avz-a11yText-A11yText"></span>
     <span aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions text" class="css-1f43avz-a11yText-A11yText"></span>
     <div class=" css-1oa51g-control">
      <div class=" css-k02lgv-ValueContainer">
       <div class=" css-1cgt3sd-placeholder">Land</div>
       <div class=" css-aic2ap-singleValue">Angola</div>
       <div class=" css-6j8wv5-Input" data-value="">
        <input class="" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="Land" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="react-select-2-listbox" aria-owns="react-select-2-listbox" role="combobox" value="" style="color: inherit; background: 0px center; opacity: 0; width: 100%; grid-area: 1 / 2 / auto / auto; font: inherit; min-width: 2px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

onSubmitFormData.submitFirstFormData('Angola')

    submitFirstFormData(land){
      cy.get("[id^=Land]").type(land+"{enter}{enter}").should('have.value',land);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `'have.text'` instead of `'have.value'`?

Comment: And are you seeing the value correctly set when viewing the test, only the assertion at the end fails? Or is Cypress failing to set the value of the input field?

Comment: 'have.text' didn't work :(. Yes the value is correctly set

Answer (score 0):

Reselect the input for the assertion. If there's a slow(ish) event handler, the way you have `.should()` chained off `.type()` my not be retrying the `.get()`.

```js
cy.get("[id^=Land]").type(land+"{enter}{enter}")
cy.get("[id^=Land]").should('have.value',land)
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(